# Can i use Nagios for testing in small company

Tags: nagios

I don;t know much about Nagios and only read that its system monitoring tool.

My company has 1

```
1)Linux VPS server
2)Internal Ubuntu server
3)Internal window 2003 server
4)Internal linux server for testing
```

I just want to have a play with Nagios and want to know that, considering myt scenario, how can Nagios help in my case or what improvement it can do for monitoring those servers

Comment: Four servers provides a great 'labratory' to learn Nagios. If you have more servers, Nagios might be too confusing at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four servers isn't too much to monitor and manage by hand, but it's still worth trying Nagios out; it's a useful tool to know how to use.  My own Nagios instance monitors server disk space/RAM/load, switch throughput, printer status/toner levels, UPS runtime, and all sorts of other stuff; you really can persuade it to monitor almost anything.  There are also add-ons that record and graph performance data, so you can get an idea of how a particular service is performing over time.

As far as implementation goes, I'd install Nagios itself on your testing Linux server, then install NRPE on the other Linux boxes and NSClient++ on the 2003 server.  Everything you need's at http://support.nagios.com/knowledgebase/officialdocs.

Comment: +1. agree. 4 servers are not too much. Nagios could be pretty heavy to set up correctly, but once is up and running and all notifications and escalations are in order, you can almost forget about it. It's rock solid and, as said, worths a test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to monitoring and Nagios, you may want to look at groundworkopensource.com. It combines Nagios with other tools to make it a little easier to manage everything. It makes configuring hosts, etc. in Nagios much easier. It doesn't hurt to start with bare Nagios, though to understand how it works.